# Can't get tkinter window title to change from 'tk'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I thought the line to change the title of a window was:

```
tk=Tk()

tk.title="my title"
```

But I can't get the title to change in my code:

```
def welcome_screen():
    #creates the login window
    window = Tk()
    window.title = "Login Screen"
    window.geometry("960x540+450+250")
    canvas = Canvas(window, width=960, height=540, bd=10, bg='#494949')
    canvas.pack()
    window.mainloop()

welcome_screen()
```

The title should change to "login screen" but when run it just says 'tk'.
everything else works as expected.

Comment: `title` is a method, not an attribute - `tk.title("my title")`.

Comment: Genius! I had the same issue too. I must be blind for not having seen that immediately... At least I'm not the only one :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`title` is a function. Use it like:

```
root.title("My new title")
```

Example:

```
root = Tk()
root.title("my title")
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3):

As @jasonharper pointed out in a comment, `title` is a method not an attribute, so you need to call it and pass the title string. Another problem with your code is that it calls `Tk()` twice, which is generally not going to work. It also looks like you using a `from tkinter import *` which is considered by many to be a poor programming practice because it can cause hard-to-debug name collisions.

So here's code that addressing all those issues:

```
import tkinter as tk

def welcome_screen():
    """ Create and display login window. """
    window = tk.Tk()
    window.title("Login Screen")
    window.geometry("960x540+450+250")
    canvas = tk.Canvas(window, width=960, height=540, bd=10, bg='#494949')
    canvas.pack()
    window.mainloop()

welcome_screen()
```